# Popover arrow not showing when popover content overflows

Tags: jquery, css

I have a vanilla popover box generated by jQuery that sometimes needs to display a long string. To maintain an appropriate size I overflowed it in order to be able to scroll inside. The problem is, when I add the overflow attribute to the popover the arrow connected to it disappears. [Here can see the problem when I toggle the overflow attribute (gif).](http://gph.is/2EbElSB)

My CSS is as follow:

```css
.popover {
  max-height: 150%;
  max-width: 35%;
  overflow: auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Provide live examples or all needed parts of code, not GIFs please

Comment: apply `overflow:scroll` in the inner element with `height`

Comment: Did you try to better define your `overflow` ? `overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: visible;`

Comment: @Zenoo I do tried all possible combinations of overflow/overflow-y/overflow-x and their possible values but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with `overflow-y: scroll`

```
.popover {
  max-height: 150%;
  max-width: 35%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```